# Android specifications for middleware developers?

Tags: android, specifications

Is there any specification document provided by Android for Hardware vendors. my question is

for example if I have have my own Bluetooth device and stack, how my bt stack can be hookup to android APIs.

Is there any spec document from google similar to micorsoft DDI spec. this is not only for Bluettoh. Any device stack.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your own Bluetooth device and stack, high probably you developed it in RFC standards. If you did not use RFC standard how that device communicate with others?

Android using **RFC** standards so confusions are eliminated.

If we talk about **NFC** standards, you can read somethings from [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/index.html)

Comment: What about NFC?, There many NFC Vendors supporting Android OS. What is the spec they follow?

Comment: @jammulak added extra line to answer

Comment: Android Compatibility Definition Document (CDD). This is what I am looking for. Thanks for the reply.